# Oracle - clean LOB files - recovering disk space

Tags: oracle

I have a friend who has a website and asked me for help.
I often use MySQL databases but never Oracle databases.
And unfortunately he has an Oracle database, so I can't find a solution.

The available disk space is slowly decreasing... I delete a lot of lines from the table but that doesn't solve his problem.
The database continues to take up disk space slowly.

I read that LOB files do not return disk space, even if you delete data.

- How can I reorganize LOB files easily with a simple request?
- (or/and) How can I recover disk space on Oracle?

```
SELECT DISTINCT VERSION FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION
```

```
12.1.0.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Only deleting lines from tables will not gain the disk space.
You need to reclaim the table space after deleting data.

I would suggest go through the Oracle documents on reclaiming space.